# Write csv with each list as column

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a dictionary that holds a two level nested list for each key that looks like the following:

```
OrderedDict([(0,[['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h']]), (1,[['i','j','k','l'],['m','n','o','p']])])
```

I would like to write each nested list to a csv as a column:

```
a,b,c,d      e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l      m,n,o,p
```

the output I am getting from my current code is:

```
['a','b','c','d']      ['e','f','g','h']
['i','j','k','l']      ['m','n','o','p']
```

The columns are correct but I would like to remove the brackets [ ] and quotes ' '

```
a,b,c,d      e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l      m,n,o,p
```

CODE:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for record in my_dict.values():
        writer.writerow(record)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The data structure you listed on the first line is not valid. Can you please correct?

Comment: @Trewq Fixed it. Look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for record in my_dict.values():
        final = [",".join(index) for index in record]
        writer.writerow(final)
```

Comment: works perfect, however, how would I deal with the record have 'n' number of indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble visualizing how your `record` looks because it seems like each value should be a nested list, meaning each column should contain both lists. If it were really writing one value from `.values()` at a time, it seems like you would get one column with both lists in it.

At any rate, what you want to achieve should probably be sought through the .join() method:

```
for record in my_dict.values():
    writer.writerow(','.join(record))
```

But the thing is, you're making a CSV (comma separated values) file, so each comma may be interpreted as a field-delimiter.

Question: Have you considered using a different delimiter when you instantiate your csv.writer?

Comment: The `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` should quote everything written to the csv, and allow commas in the text without it being a delimiter.The `record` is the the entries in the `OrderedDict` in my post.

Comment: getting `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found` from your recommended code.

Comment: In my answer, the loop works fine, you might need to update the parameters for the `writer` object though.

Comment: I am remembering now: it writes out the list as a row of fields. I see how you fixed it.